# how to disable payment method even is active

Tags: shipping-methods, payment-methods

I have a "Custom Shipping Method" and have 3 payment methods... Want to show one of these 3 payment methods if 1 of the fields in system.xml of "my custom shipping" is "1" and also my "custom shipping" is active and if "custom shipping" is not active, do not display it even the field is "1" in system.xml from backend and then only show 2 others

Is this possible? if yes, How can set it in my codes?

This is my observer but do not work

```
public function paymentMethodIsActive($observer)
    {
        $event  = $observer->getEvent();
        $method = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result = $event->getResult();

        $activeCarrier = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/mycarrier/active');
        $activeCustom  = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/mycarrier/custom');

        if ($method->getCode()  == 'payment_method') {
            if ($activeCarrier == '1' && $activeCustom == '1') {
                $result->isAvailable = true;
            } else {
                $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event  `payment_method_is_active`.

It is dispatched in the method `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isAvailable()`.
You have 3 objects passed to the event:

result - what you need to modify to make the method not active
method_instance - the payment method instance
quote - the current quote

Your observer method can look something like this:

```
public function checkPaymentAvailability($observer) {
    $methodInstance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
    if ($methodInstance->getCode()  != 'your payment method code here') {
        return $this; //if it's not the payment method your a looking for do nothing
    }
    $shouldNotBeAvailable = ...your code that derermines if the payment method should be available or not.

    if (!$shouldNotBeAvailable) {
        //if the payment method should not be available then mark it as not available.
         $result = $observer->getResult();
         $result->isAvailable = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marius, but it not depend of my "custom shipping method" ... I want to don't display "payment method" when "custom shipping and one filed in config.xml" is set to "No", even "payment method" is active

Comment: What I just answered should get the result you want. Just replace `your code that determines if the payment method should be available` with your code that checks if your custom shipping and an other field from config.xml is set to NO

Comment: I updated my first code with my codes, can you check it now?

Comment: What values do you get in your code for `$activeCarrier` and `$activeCustom`?

Comment: both of them are from "yesno" means `<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>`

Comment: get `"0"` in both or `"0"` for `$activeCarrier` and `"1"` for `$activeCustom`

Comment: hmmm..this is strange. In this case your payment method should not be visible in the checkout